# Error "expectedcss(css-rparentexpected)" on importing css url in angular

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, tslint

I am getting below red error mark in VS code in css file at "400italic". How should I fix this?

Error:-    `) expectedcss(css-rparentexpected);`

## .css

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400, 400italic, 600, 600italic, 700, 700italic);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning of `css-rparentexpected` is "Right parenthesis expected", as you can see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-css-languageservice/blob/master/src/parser/cssErrors.ts#L44).

The solution is simple, remove all the spaces in the URL, it still works: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic

Answer (score 0):

**Use ' ' inside url bracket like**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400, 400italic, 600, 600italic, 700, 700italic');
```